# Vulkan vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices Returning Unexpected Device Count

Tags: vulkan

In the machine I'm running I have two GTX 980 Tis.
When I query the physical device count with `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` it always returns 1 despite having 2 physical discrete graphics cards. When I use `vulkaninfo` the only device listed is `GPU0` which is a `DISCRETE_GPU` / `GTX 980 Ti`.

This happens in Windows 10 as well as GNU/Linux 4.5 using Vulkan API 1.0.11 with proprietary Nvidia drivers.

Is this normal behavior and I'm not using the API correctly or is this a bug? I feel like I've made a glaring obvious mistake but I can't find anything in the Vulkan specification about it.

For clarity, this is exactly how I query physical device count:

```
auto deviceCount = uint32_t{0};
instance.enumeratePhysicalDevices(&deviceCount, nullptr);
// At this point deviceCount is 1
```

Also, to confirm that the OS sees the cards:

Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\matt>wmic path win32_VideoController get name
Name
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti
```

[image: GPUs in Nvidia Driver Settings]

Linux 4.5:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 364.19     Driver Version: 364.19         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
|  0%   56C    P8    34W / 300W |    444MiB /  6140MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P8    25W / 300W |     22MiB /  6143MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

[image: GPUs in Nvidia XServer Settings]

Comment: Integrated GPU is often (?) inactivated by the motherboard if a discrete GPU is found. Is it visible in the device manager?

Comment: That's not a factor here, I don't care about the integrated GPU, only the discrete GPUs.

Comment: Ok. Are you able to display anything using both discrete GPU:s?

Comment: Yes, of course, I've attached more information to show that both Win10 and Linux are picking the cards up. I've used both of the cards for CUDA as well as SLI with Direct3D and OpenGL.

Comment: You should pass NULL as last parameter, not nullptr. Won't fix it I think but it is worth a shot.

Comment: I'm using `vk_cpp.hpp` as a C++ wrapper around `vulkan.h` using G++ 5.3.0 and Clang++ 3.7.1 with the std set to C++14, `nullptr` is the correct usage for this and `NULL` will make no difference. Not only that, but given that `vulkaninfo` only provides one GPU I'd guess that this is a global issue with configuration less to do with the semantics of how I pass a nullptr, plus the deviceCount doesn't change (by design) when I call `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` again to populate the list of GPUs with actual PhysicalDevice instances.

Comment: @Andreas nullptr and NULL differ only in that NULL can be misinterpreted as an integer literal, they're both interpreted as null pointer constants in a pointer context.

Comment: @LarsViklund True. My point was the vulkan reference states the parameter shall be NULL. It does not say it shall be null pointer :) If there is risk of misinterpretation it is so by design by the smart people at Khronos. https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices.html

Comment: @Andreas, that's just simply not how this works in C++, I don't mean to discount your opinions, but this is just a completely irrelevant argument to the question at hand.

Comment: You do not use the function according to the API reference. Look I'll prove my point elsewere. This is not the place. Good luck finding the problem. (Which I can't imagine is because of the null pointer just to be clear)

Comment: You need to have drivers for both GPUs installed.

Comment: @ratchetfreak what leads you to believe I don't? I've already said they both work together quite well, is there further configuration to be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [LunarG FAQ](https://lunarg.com/frequently-asked-questions/):

> **There is no multiple GPU support in version 1.0. That was unfortunately a feature Khronos had to cut in order to preserve
>   schedule. It is expected to be near the top of the list for Vulkan
>   1.1. It is perfectly possible for a Vulkan implementation to expose multiple GPUs. What Vulkan currently can’t do is allow resource
>   sharing between them. So from a point of view of, for example, a
>   Windows system manager, its possible to recognize multiple ways to
>   render to a surface and then use operating system hooks to transfer
>   that to the screen. What Vulkan doesn’t have is the ability to share a
>   texture or a render target between multiple GPUs.**

I'd write this issue off as being something that wasn't implemented because it wasn't required that they implement it yet. When Vulkan adds better multi-GPU support to be required in their spec these issues will most likely be fixed. It is odd that it still won't expose the GPUs available, but even if it did, Vulkan 1.0.x isn't ready for utilizing multiple GPUs in a way that would benefit games.

**Update as of 7/23/2016: With Nvidia GeForce driver v368.69 multiple GPUs are visible to Vulkan.**

Without changing anything (still using Vulkan API v1.0.11) and updating to Nvidia's latest driver, I have full access to both physical devices on my machine, this doesn't mean that Multi-GPU support is quite here, but it's the first step in Vulkan even being a viable choice when developing a game.

Answer (score 0):

You should've disabled/removed the SLI bridge.
That's the ***glaring obvious mistake*** I'm seeing here AFAIK.

Comment: That has absolutely no bearing on it, see my answer, it has been solved.

Comment: @MattJensJensen At the time of this question, NVIDIA's implementation was showing the SLI combo and not individual cards, that's what I'm referring to.

Comment: No, it wasn't for me, without the SLI bridge, only one card was visible.